# CSS Positioning issue (Split Button Dropdown) - unable to move an element to another side and sit next to a button

Tags: html, css

CSS has been my greatest weakness and even after a few tutorials here and there, I am still quite a novice in terms of positioning things.

I would like to move a drop-down hover button next to another button (split button dropdown). However even after using `position:auto` and  `left:auto`, it is still showing up on the other side, where I do not want it to be in. Looking for a HTML/CSS guru that can show this novice the way :)

Here is a picture of what I'm talking about:

[Element I want moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIaxn.png)

The way I would like the Split Button to look like (note: just the positioning of one another, not the colour or size etc..).

[Split Button Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7krGV.png)

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<!-- Font Awesome Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- The "All Referral" Dropdown hover button -->
<button class="btn">All Referral</button>
<div class="dropdown">
  <!-- The Dropdown button with the arrow and the links -->  
  <button class="btn" style="border-left:1px solid orange">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>

  <!-- The links for all referral in the dropdown button -->
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.btn {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 20px 3px 20px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  padding: 2px 20px 3px 20px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;   
  /* position: absolute;  */
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: silver;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: orange}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.btn:hover, .dropdown:hover .btn  {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

Also are there any youtube tutorials or absolutely handy pdf/books whatever for "semi-advanced" css tips and tricks? I kinda have an idea with the basics but it's just so difficult for me to move things around the page and where it should go etc...

Again, many thanks for any help that comes my way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The HTML Code:

```
<!-- Font Awesome Icon Library -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

            <!-- The "All Referral" Dropdown hover button -->
            <div id="buttonContainer"> <!--BUTTON CONTAINER-->
            
            <button id="button">All Referral</button> <!--CHANGED TO ID -->
            <div class="dropdown">
                <!-- The Dropdown button with the arrow and the links -->  
                <button id="dropButton" style="border-left:1px solid orange"> <!--CHANGED TO ID -->
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                
                <!-- The links for all referral in the dropdown button -->
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            </div>


            <span style="float:left;">
                    <a class="btnWhiteblueMin marleft" href="#">Button 1</a>
                    <a class="btnWhiteblueMin marleft" href="#">Button 2</a>
                    <a class="btnWhitepurpleMin" href="#">Button 3</a>
                </span>
            <br class="clr" /> 
            
        </div>
```

### The CSS Code:

```
/* Participant Profile Header Drop-down Button -CoachPanda Edit */
/* Dropdown Button */
#buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  float: right; /*Q change*/
}

#button {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 20px 3px 20px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#dropButton {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {  
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 14px;    /*Q change */ 
  right: 0px;
  /* position: absolute;  */
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  font-size: 14px;  /*Q change font size*/    
  display: none;  
  position: absolute;
  background-color: silver;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: orange}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.btn:hover, .dropdown:hover .btn  {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using flexbox for positioning. Take a look at the link below.
https://codepen.io/jcbryant/pen/dyObVbL

What I did: added a `div` container wrapped around the buttons. Gave each button its own unique `id` for better control. Removed the `float` properties and replaced them with `display: flex`. Removed the `padding` property on the drop down button and added `margin-left: 0px;`.

Comment: Hello Jason Bryant, I appreciate the response. The changes are good, and I think we are almost there. Putting in the changes you made, this is the current look: https://imgur.com/IN28sBM

Comment: Please disregard the image above, I do not know why our hosting takes forever to actually apply the changes like this. But here is what it actually looks like now: https://imgur.com/O2VD8t3

Comment: It would help to see the rest of the code containing the edit profile, but you can put the edit profile inside of the same div, then use flex-direction and margin to achieve the desired postioning.

Comment: Pardon my late reply. Thanks to your guidance, the button is now in the "right" place. I could not have done it without your help! https://codepen.io/AYSCodePen/pen/wvoBmYy

Answer (score 0):

Do a `display: flex;` on the container of that All refferals button and the dropdown then do margin-left: 0; in the `.dropdown btn`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have tried this, but it just moved the split drop down button in a weird way on the page, and was centering itself in the middle for some reason